# Why key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 is unsupported?

Tags: jruby, net-ssh

I'am trying to use ruby gem `net-ssh` and  receive the error described bellow

```
jruby-9.1.15.0 :001 > require "net/ssh"
 => true 
jruby-9.1.15.0 :002 > Net::SSH.start('myhost.dev', 'username' password: 'password', verbose: Logger::DEBUG){|ssh| puts ssh.exec!('hostname')}
D, [2018-01-17T14:24:29.633089 #26123] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[7d0]: establishing connection to myhost.dev:22
D, [2018-01-17T14:24:29.884816 #26123] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[7d0]: connection established
I, [2018-01-17T14:24:29.888234 #26123]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[7d2]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2018-01-17T14:24:29.888926 #26123] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[7d2]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_4.2.0 java'
D, [2018-01-17T14:24:29.952538 #26123] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[7d2]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8'
NotImplementedError: unsupported key type `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'
        from /home/qpi/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0@some_gem/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:286:in `read_keyblob'
```

Error was raised from `buffer.rb:286:in read_keyblob`. 
[Here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/a30357a3c7bea51e7656f8237527a063eea9b308/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb#L286) the part of code which raising the error

```
unless defined?(OpenSSL::PKey::EC)
    raise NotImplementedError, "unsupported key type `#{type}'"
```

Ok.. lets check, defined `OpenSSL::PKey::EC` or not:

```
jruby-9.1.15.0 :003 > defined?(OpenSSL::PKey::EC) ? 'defined' : 'not defined'
 => "defined"
```

What am I doing wrong?

When i use `ruby` (not `jruby`), everything works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a real solution but I found a hack that does the trick for me.

https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl/issues/105

In short, before your Net::SFTP.start, put these 2 lines.

`Net::SSH::Transport::Algorithms::ALGORITHMS.values.each { |algs| algs.reject! { |a| a =~ /^ecd(sa|h)-sha2/ } }
Net::SSH::KnownHosts::SUPPORTED_TYPE.reject! { |t| t =~ /^ecd(sa|h)-sha2/ }`

and your problem should be gone.